# Explicit cast reading .csv with case class Spark 2.1.0

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I have the following case class:

```
case class OrderDetails(OrderID : String, ProductID : String, UnitPrice : Double,
                    Qty : Int, Discount : Double)
```

I am trying read this csv: https://github.com/xsankar/fdps-v3/blob/master/data/NW-Order-Details.csv

This is my code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master(sparkMaster).appName(sparkAppName).getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val orderDetails = spark.read.option("header","true").csv( inputFiles + "NW-Order-Details.csv").as[OrderDetails]
```

And the error is:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
 Cannot up cast `UnitPrice` from string to double as it may truncate
 The type path of the target object is:
  - field (class: "scala.Double", name: "UnitPrice")
  - root class: "es.own3dh2so4.OrderDetails"
 You can either add an explicit cast to the input data or choose a higher precision type of the field in the target object;
```

Why can not it be transformed if all fields are "doubles" values? What do not I understand?

Spark version 2.1.0, Scala version 2.11.7

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to explicitly cast your field to a `Double`:

```
val orderDetails = spark.read
   .option("header","true")
   .csv( inputFiles + "NW-Order-Details.csv")
   .withColumn("unitPrice", 'UnitPrice.cast(DoubleType))
   .as[OrderDetails]
```

On a side note, by Scala (and Java) convention, your case class constructor parameters should be lower camel case:

```
case class OrderDetails(orderID: String, 
                        productID: String, 
                        unitPrice: Double,
                        qty: Int, 
                        discount: Double)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just found the following property that can happen to you and infers you all fields `option("inferSchema","true")`.

About Scala convenion I used upper camel case because is needed because the csv header is uppercase

Comment: In my experience, that only sometimes works for this situation. If that's all it takes, that's cool.

Comment: As for the convention thing, there are a lot of ways around that--for example, by naming the columns as you want them to be using `toDf`. But I can see why that feels like unnecessary busywork. I am personally just really big on convention--on professional projects in particular so my code passes static analysis tests and code reviews.

Answer (score 12):

If we want to change the datatype for multiple columns; if we use withColumn option it will look ugly.
The better way to apply schema for the data is

1. Get the Case Class schema using Encoders as shown below

   ```
   val caseClassschema = Encoders.product[CaseClass].schema
   ```
2. Apply this schema while reading data

   ```
   val data = spark.read.schema(caseClassschema)
   ```

Comment: I also think this approach is better.