# How to rename existing spark dataframe from case class values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've created a dataframe from reading a csv. Now i wanted to rename the columns and datatypes as per mentioned in the case class MyData.

```
case class MyData(
                   id: String,
                   name: String,
                   pcode: Integer,
                   loc: String)

val inputDF=spark.read.csv("/examples/example.csv")

inputDF.printSchema

scala> inputDF.printSchema
root
 |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c3: string (nullable = true)
```

is there any way I can change the schema of inputDF to the one given in case class , want to rename the column as well as modify the
datatypes as well.

Is there any way I can rename the columns and datatypes of inputDF to the one given in the case class.
_c0 renamed to id, _c1 renamed to name,_c2 renamed to pcode ,_c3 renamed to loc plus the datatypes formatted according to case class.
Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55527384/1374437), you can first obtain a Spark schema from the case class:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

val mySchema = Encoders.product[MyData].schema

// scala> mySchema.printTreeString
// root
//  |-- id: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- pcode: integer (nullable = true)
//  |-- loc: string (nullable = true)
```

then supply it while reading the CSV file. Use `as[MyData]` to obtain a typed dataset:

```scala
val inputDF = spark.read
                .schema(mySchema)
                .csv("/examples/example.csv")
                .as[MyData]
```

Even without `as[MyData]`, the untyped dataframe will still have all the correctly-named columns with their respective types:

```scala
scala> val inputDF = spark.read.schema(mySchema).csv("/tmp/example.csv")
inputDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, name: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> inputDF.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pcode: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- loc: string (nullable = true)

scala> val typedInputDF = inputDF.as[MyData]
typedInputDF: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[MyData] = [id: string, name: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> typedInputDF.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pcode: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- loc: string (nullable = true)
```